# C# JsonConvert Error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this Json Return:

```
[
{
  "url": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "code": 0, 
  "aplication": 
  {
    "version":
    [
    {
       "silent": true, 
       "checksum": "9aabad09b09459ac6c9e54f9ca4eb5c4",
       "size": 1250619, 
       "force": true, 
       "apply_message": "", 
       "id": 116,
       "id_aplication": 4, 
       "number": "1.0.5.0", 
       "news": "", 
       "automatic": true, 
       "installation": "Setup.exe"
    }
    ], 
    "division_name": "DNT",
    "app_name": "MyApplication", 
    "id": 4, 
    "id_master": 0
}, 
"message": "New Application Found"
}
]
```

Using this site http://json2csharp.com/, i generate these classes:

```
public class Version
{
    public bool silent { get; set; }
    public string checksum { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public bool force { get; set; }
    public string apply_message { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_aplication { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string news { get; set; }
    public bool automatic { get; set; }
    public string installation { get; set; }
}


public class Aplication
{
    public List<Version> version { get; set; }
    public string division_name { get; set; }
    public string app_name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_master { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public Aplication aplication { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my C# code, i write this:

```
RootObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResult);
```

But, i receive this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleAPP.Aplication]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'aplication.version', line 1,
>   position 227.

I read some tips about this, but not helps to me. For example:

[Unable to parse JSON array in WCF REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463556/unable-to-parse-json-array-in-wcf-rest)

Comment: I read this tip, too. But not works.

Comment: Probably not an issue here, but I'd change the name of the `Version` class since .NET already has a [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class.

Comment: @Eduardo: Then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is an array - it only contains one item, but it's still an array. If you remove the leading and trailing `[` and `]` from the big JSON string, it should deserialize fine.

Or you can deserialize into `RootObject[]` instead of `RootObject`.

Either way will work.

Comment: I had already removed these trailing. Not works. :(

Comment: I just tried both ways - deserializing into `RootObject[]` with the original JSON, and removing the outer brackets and deserializing into `RootObject` - both worked just fine.